# Wrong link for tag-wiki edits privilege

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

On the Tag-Wiki edit page, the [tag wiki edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) link points to the [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) page, when it should probably point to [Tag Wiki Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) instead.

[image]

Comment: Well, no this is correct. You need to be a "trusted user" in order to edit tags without requiring a review (quote "Editing tag wikis without needing approval"), hence the yellow message box. The "tag wiki edit" rights just enable you to even open the edit page.

Comment: @Top That's confusing, and should be documented. If tag-wiki editing were my favorite, would-be privilege, then I'd be really disappointed at 5,000 rep. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is linking to the correct place.

At 5,000 reputation you can only *suggest* edits to tag wikis, similar to users suggesting edits to post when below the 2,000 reputation mark.

At 20,000 reputation, you gain the ability to edit tag wikis without needing approval. The message is correctly telling you that you don't have that privilege yet and, because of that fact, your edit will need peer reviewed before it goes live.

Comment: I see. Perhaps the "Tag Wiki Edits" page should mention this. Thanks.